# Mediacontroller on fragment is hiding when back is pressed

Tags: android, fragment, mediacontroller

I've a `fragment` where I've used **MediaPlayer** and **MediaController**. Both are working fine. The problem is when I press the back key the media controller becomes hidden but **MediaPlayer** continues to play. If I press back button again then `onBackPressed` method is called which is in the `fragment` container `activity`. Though `onBackPressed` is changing the `fragment` to the previous one but **Mediaplayer** is still running.

I wish to get to know how can I make things in a way so that back press would go to the previous fragment and will also hide the media controller and at the same time media player should be stopped.

Here I'm giving the code.

```
package com.codetrio.alquran;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.MediaController;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.VideoView;

import com.codetrio.alquran.com.codetrio.alquran.util.ChapterDetailAdapter;
import com.codetrio.alquran.db.ChapterDataSource;
import com.codetrio.alquran.model.Chapter;
import com.codetrio.alquran.model.Verse;
import com.codetrio.alquran.db.VerseDataSource;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 * Activities that contain this fragment must implement the
 * {@link ChapterDetailsFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener} interface
 * to handle interaction events.
 * Use the {@link ChapterDetailsFragment#newInstance} factory method to
 * create an instance of this fragment.
 */
public class ChapterDetailsFragment extends Fragment implements MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener, MediaController.MediaPlayerControl {
    // TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
    // the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
    private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
    private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

    // TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
    private String mParam1;
    private String mParam2;
    private int pageCount = 0, startFrom = 0, endTo = 4, chapterId, banglaChapterId;

    private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;
    ListView lvChapterDetails;
    ChapterDetailAdapter chapterDetailAdapter;
    Button btnPrevious, btnNext;
    Chapter chapter, banglaChapter;

    List<Verse> verses = new ArrayList<Verse>();
    List<Verse> banglaVerses = new ArrayList<Verse>();
    List<Verse> versesPortion = new ArrayList<Verse>();
    List<Verse> banglaVersesPortion = new ArrayList<Verse>();

    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
    MediaController mediaController;
    private Handler handler = new Handler();
    View tempFragView, increaseFont, decreaseFont;
    LinearLayout linearLayout;

    float fontSize = 14;

    public ChapterDetailsFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    /**
     * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
     * this fragment using the provided parameters.
     *
     * @param param1 Parameter 1.
     * @param param2 Parameter 2.
     * @return A new instance of fragment ChapterDetailsFragment.
     */
    // TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
    public static ChapterDetailsFragment newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
        ChapterDetailsFragment fragment = new ChapterDetailsFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
            mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final View fragView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_chapter_details, container, false);
        tempFragView = fragView;
        btnPrevious = (Button) fragView.findViewById(R.id.btnPrev);
        btnNext = (Button) fragView.findViewById(R.id.btnNext);
        linearLayout = fragView.findViewById(R.id.forMediaController);

        increaseFont = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.btnIncreaseFont);
        decreaseFont = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.btnDecreaseFont);
        increaseFont.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        decreaseFont.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        Bundle bundle = getArguments();//.getString("GO_TO_LAST_READ");

        if( bundle != null && bundle.containsKey("GO_TO_LAST_READ") && bundle.getString("GO_TO_LAST_READ").equals("true")){
            SharedPreferences sharedPref = getActivity().getSharedPreferences(
                    getString(R.string.shared_pref_name), Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            chapterId = sharedPref.getInt("chapter_id", -1);
            pageCount = sharedPref.getInt("page_count", -1);
            if(chapterId == -1){
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "No last read condition found. Please read a chapter first", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                btnPrevious.setEnabled(false);
                btnNext.setEnabled(false);
            }
            if(pageCount > -1){
                startFrom = (pageCount-1)*4 + 4;
                endTo = startFrom + 4;
            }
        }else{
            chapterId = Integer.parseInt(getArguments().getString("chapter_id"));
            banglaChapterId = Integer.parseInt(getArguments().getString("bangla_chapter_id"));
        }
        ChapterDataSource chapterDataSource = new ChapterDataSource(getActivity());
        chapterDataSource.open();
        banglaChapter = chapterDataSource.getChapterById(banglaChapterId, 0);
        chapter = chapterDataSource.getChapterById(chapterId, 1);
        chapterDataSource.close();
        getActivity().setTitle(banglaChapter.getChapterName());

        VerseDataSource verseDataSource = new VerseDataSource(getActivity());
        verseDataSource.open();
        verses = verseDataSource.getVersesByChapter( (chapterId), 1);
        banglaVerses = verseDataSource.getVersesByChapter( (chapterId), 0);
        verseDataSource.close();

        for(int i=startFrom; i<endTo; i++){
            if(i<verses.size()) {
                Verse verse = verses.get(i);
                versesPortion.add(verse);
                Verse bangla = banglaVerses.get(i);
                banglaVersesPortion.add(bangla);
            }
        }
        chapterDetailAdapter = new ChapterDetailAdapter((ArrayList<Verse>) versesPortion, (ArrayList<Verse>) banglaVersesPortion, getContext(), fontSize);
        lvChapterDetails = (ListView) fragView.findViewById(R.id.lvDetails);
        lvChapterDetails.setAdapter(chapterDetailAdapter);
        File file = new File("/data/data/com.codetrio.alquran/"+Integer.toString(chapter.getId())+".mp3");
        if(file.exists()){
            playAudio(file);
        }else{
            Log.i("NOOOO", "file not found");
        }
        increaseFont.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                fontSize += 2;
                chapterDetailAdapter = new ChapterDetailAdapter((ArrayList<Verse>) versesPortion, (ArrayList<Verse>) banglaVersesPortion, getContext(), fontSize);
                lvChapterDetails.setAdapter(chapterDetailAdapter);
            }
        });
        decreaseFont.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                fontSize -= 2;
                chapterDetailAdapter = new ChapterDetailAdapter((ArrayList<Verse>) versesPortion, (ArrayList<Verse>) banglaVersesPortion, getContext(), fontSize);
                lvChapterDetails.setAdapter(chapterDetailAdapter);
            }
        });
        if(pageCount<1) { //for the first page previous button should be disabled
            btnPrevious.setEnabled(false);
        }

        btnPrevious.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                pageCount--;
                updateListView();
                updateLastRead(chapterId, pageCount);
                btnNext.setEnabled(true);
                if(pageCount==0){
                    btnPrevious.setEnabled(false);
                }
            }
        });
        btnNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                pageCount++;
                updateListView();
                updateLastRead(chapterId, pageCount);
                btnPrevious.setEnabled(true);
            }
        });
        updateLastRead(chapterId, pageCount);
        return fragView;
    }

    /**
     *
     */
    public void updateListView(){
        startFrom = (pageCount-1)*4 + 4;
        endTo = startFrom + 4;
        if(startFrom < verses.size()) {
            chapterDetailAdapter.clear();
            versesPortion.clear();
            banglaVersesPortion.clear();

            for (int i = startFrom; i < endTo; i++) {
                if (i < verses.size()) {
                    Verse verse = verses.get(i);
                    versesPortion.add(verse);
                    Verse bangla = banglaVerses.get(i);
                    banglaVersesPortion.add(bangla);
                }else{
                    btnNext.setEnabled(false);
                    btnPrevious.setEnabled(true);
                }
            }
            chapterDetailAdapter = new ChapterDetailAdapter((ArrayList<Verse>) versesPortion, (ArrayList<Verse>) banglaVersesPortion, getContext(), fontSize);
            lvChapterDetails.setAdapter(chapterDetailAdapter);
        }else{
            btnNext.setEnabled(false);
            btnPrevious.setEnabled(true);
        }
    }

    private void playAudio(File file){
        if(mediaPlayer != null && mediaPlayer.isPlaying()){
            mediaPlayer.stop();
            mediaController.hide();
        }
        mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this.getActivity(), Uri.fromFile(file));
        mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(this);

        mediaController = new MediaController(this.getActivity());
        mediaPlayer.start();
    }

    /**
     * Keeping the last read in shared preferences
     * @param chapterId
     * @param pageCount
     */
    public void updateLastRead(int chapterId, int pageCount){
        SharedPreferences sharefPref = getActivity().getSharedPreferences(getString(R.string.shared_pref_name), Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharefPref.edit();
        editor.putInt("chapter_id", chapterId);
        editor.putInt("page_count", pageCount);
        editor.commit();
    }

    // TODO: Rename method, update argument and hook method into UI event
    public void onButtonPressed(Uri uri) {
        if (mListener != null) {
            mListener.onFragmentInteraction(uri);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        if (context instanceof OnFragmentInteractionListener) {
            mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) context;
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                    + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mListener = null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
        try{
            mediaController.setMediaPlayer(this);
            mediaController.setAnchorView(linearLayout);
            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    mediaController.setEnabled(true);
                    mediaController.show(0);
                }
            });
        }catch (Exception e){
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void start() {
        mediaPlayer.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void pause() {
        mediaPlayer.pause();
    }

    @Override
    public int getDuration() {
        return mediaPlayer.getDuration();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCurrentPosition() {
        return mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
    }

    @Override
    public void seekTo(int i) {
        mediaPlayer.seekTo(i);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isPlaying() {
        return mediaPlayer.isPlaying();
    }

    @Override
    public int getBufferPercentage() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean canPause() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean canSeekBackward() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean canSeekForward() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public int getAudioSessionId() {
        return 0;
    }

    /**
     * This interface must be implemented by activities that contain this
     * fragment to allow an interaction in this fragment to be communicated
     * to the activity and potentially other fragments contained in that
     * activity.
     * <p>
     * See the Android Training lesson <a href=
     * "http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html"
     * >Communicating with Other Fragments</a> for more information.
     */
    public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
        // TODO: Update argument type and name
        void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
    }

    public void stopMediaPlayer(){
        mediaPlayer.stop();
        mediaPlayer = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is the code?

Comment: stopMediaPlayer() The method has no use.